# Why is there an extra bracket surrounding this JSON string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to generate JSON to be read by my smartphone application, however I am confused about why I have an outer "[]" on the JSON structure. This is my JSON:

```
[{"article":{"title":"First"}},{"article":{"title":"Ontario"}}]
```

and this is a represention of my article index. Is there a way to remove the `[]` because, to my understanding, they're not proper JSON.

Here's how I produce it:

```
respond_with :json
def index
  @articles= Article.all
  respond_with @articles.as_json(:root => true, :only => [:title])
end
```

Comment: You have an array of two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a JSON array -

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

A JSONArray is an ordered sequence of values. Its external text form is a string wrapped in square brackets with commas separating the values. The internal form is an object having get and opt methods for accessing the values by index, and put methods for adding or replacing values. The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.

The constructor can convert a JSON text into a Java object. The toString method converts to JSON text.

Answer (score 3):

It's proper JSON. It's used to denote an array --  in this case, an array of articles. It is likely you will want to keep it like that for your web service.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]`'s on the outside simply create an array.  You're serializing multiple articles, so this is the most natural way to output them as a list.

Comment: Thank you, i will mark one as good but got to wait, then it must be the parse who is wrong